# Make QGIS wait in for loop on condition

Tags: editing, pyqgis-3, while

The goal is to check whether the user has added a point to a layer, and wait until then

Unfortunately, [using `QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55346504/9447180) did not suffice.

`time.sleep()` inside a while loop on condition does not work, since QGIS will freeze its own Python engine with `time.sleep`

This is my best effort:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

# create layer
points_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(points_layer)

# get feature coint in points layer before editing
count_before_editing = points_layer.featureCount()
print("count_before_editing", count_before_editing)

# check wether the layer is editable
if not points_layer.isEditable():
    #make it editable
    points_layer.startEditing()
    # check if the requestet point feature has been set
    while points_layer.featureCount()<count_before_editing+1:
        print(points_layer.featureCount())
        # here i am missing the functionality to wait, while I manually add a point to the points layer
        #break is only here, to prevent your qgis from remaining in while
        break
    # stop editing and commit changes
    points_layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you are choosing the "right" approach. You would better use Qt signals to catch changes in the layer.

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

# create layer
points_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(points_layer)

def featureAdded(featureid):
    print(points_layer.getFeature(featureid))

# Signal will be executed without caring about if feature added has been committed
points_layer.featureAdded.connect(featureAdded)

def committedFeaturesAdded(layerId, featureList):
    print(layerId, featureList) 

# Signal will be executed only after committed
points_layer.committedFeaturesAdded.connect(committedFeaturesAdded)
```

Comment: But how do let my user edit the layer, while the script is running and catching signals?

Comment: You just use the native edit from QGIS and you listen to these changes. Don't really understand why you want a running and blocking script. You execute my script one time and then, each time our user will edit, it will execute the code in the function (in my case, two functions, listening to 2 events).

Comment: I did not know of this particular functionality. It seems I am still using it wrong by opening the script with the processing toolbox and running it. It does end immediately, although creating the points layer.

Comment: Ok pls forgive my stupidity, your script works. I just did not know what to look for in the console.

Comment: Your answer was correct on my specific question, though I must admit I was too precise. The ultimate goal was to loop over a feature collection and only continue the looping if the point feature was set. This answer does permit to access the signal from inside the for loop, yet still fails to make the UI accessible to add the point feature, while in the for loop. It seems It's not possible to do this without threading, am i wrong?